# Validate string to start with a letter, contain at least 3 letters and contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores

Tags: php, regex, string, validation

I am trying to learn regular expressions and am stuck trying to write the pattern for the following:

1. Must start with a letter.
2. Can contain letters, numbers or underscores.
3. Must have at least 3 letters in the whole string.

What I have tried:

```
'#^[a-z0-9_]+$#i' // this one just matches the characters I want
```

And this is where I am stuck:

```
'#^[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9_]+$#i' // doesn't work
```

I read http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html, but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'#^[a-zA-Z]([0-9_]*[a-zA-Z]){2}[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$#'
```

`[a-zA-Z]` checks for the first constraint (start with a letter)

`([0-9_]*[a-zA-Z]){2}`checks for the second contraint (there must be 3 letters in total)

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` release previous contraints and only is restricted to use the allowed characters

Comment: The second constraint in your regex is two consecutive letters, not "3 letters in total". It would prohibit `A1_B2_C3`. An assertion would be easier. Also `/i` flag.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
#^[a-zA-Z]{1}(\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*){2}$#i
```

Explanation:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1}  // 1st character is a letter
(\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*){2}$ // The rest of the body contains exactly 2 letters, and 0 or more of any other word characters (letter, number, underscore)
```

Answer (score 0):

`/^(?:[a-z]\w*){3}$/i`

This pattern will require the full string to contain three repetitions of a letter followed by zero or more word characters (`\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).  The `\w` in the third repetition will consume all remaining word characters in the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Wj9d3))

```
$tests = [
    '7hello',
    'Fooey',
    'Shoo3y',
    'Whoa!',
    'A1_B2_C3_',
    '_ABC',
    'UB40',
    'omg',
    'Hi_',
    'Stackoverflow_',
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    printf(
        "%s : %s\n",
        $test,
        preg_match('/^(?:[a-z]\w*){3}$/i', $test)
            ? 'pass'
            : 'fail'
    );
}
```

Output:

```
7hello : fail
Fooey : pass
Shoo3y : pass
Whoa! : fail
A1_B2_C3_ : pass
_ABC : fail
UB40 : fail
omg : pass
Hi_ : fail
Stackoverflow_ : pass
```